# What is actual difference between Pranan and Prana?

Tags: yoga-sutras

Can anyone site Yogic references with Pranan and Prana? As of now, I know Prana is a Vayu among 10 Vayus but few days back I came across the word Pranan and it is stated its different from Prana vayu. If so, what is the difference between them and what is the function of Pranan?

Comment: Where have you heard the word 'Pranan'? Can you share the reference? Perhaps it is a Tamil variation of Prana?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - Just checking in Tamil. Reference is in a book of Asanas/Mudras which I dont know how to share here. No it's not tamil variation. In Tamil = VASI. Now I am suspecting is VASI the Pranan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pranan is Soul and it is different from Prana Vayu. Soul in the body will be only one that operates all ten Vayus and sapta dhatus and Pancha kosa of body. As we know the body is made of matter and it needs to be guided by energy. This life force is called Pranan or Soul. The soul changes the body at the time of death. Soul repairs/maintains the body with the help of dasha dhatus.
This is the base theory of Pranic healing process.

Comment: I too heard similar like that Pranan is in crown of head.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Answer (score 2):

In a South Indian language called Malayalam, there is the word pranan and it means life force. In this language, when someone says that pranan has left, it means that the person, whose Pranan left has died. Malayalam is mixture of tamil and sanskrit. Another similar example is the sanskrit word "jiva" which is the word "jivan" in Malayalam. Sanskrit word prana also means life force, breath etc. Prana is also one of the ten vayus as per ayurveda / hatha yoga. 
The etymological source of the word, prana, has roots in Sanskrit and therefore we can be confident that there is no other  meaning to it than as used in sanskrit.